# How do I create alias for Jekyll static site on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, url-rewriting, jekyll

I have a Jekyll site running on Heroku.

After site generation, I have a file created `public/photos.html`. How do I set up Jekyll/Heroku to allow me to access the page as `domain.com/photos` instead of `domain.com/photos.html`?

And I'd prefer NOT to have to use `rack-rewrite` which stands up rack middleware. Seems a bit much for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way is to just name the file `photos/index.html` instead of `photos.html`. If that doesn't work for you, you can use the variable `permalink` in the [Front Matter](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do route matching in Sinatra and serve whatever pages you like, see: http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html

Comment: Like I mentioned in my question, I'd rather not have to setup middleware to accomplish this simple task. I want to keep this a static site, generated with jekyll, without introducing rack middleware.

Comment: @MatthewBoston: You could serve the site using Jekyll's included web server, but that's not really intended for production. Otherwise, you're going to have to use a (relatively simple) piece of Rack middleware or a Sinatra app.

Comment: @MatthewBoston: misread your question on 'Jekyll' as 'Octopress' for some reason... If you deploy to Heroku, AFAIK you'll be using Webrick as the webserver whether you like it or not, and you don't have the option of redirects/rewrites. I've read posts on creating a Heroku custom buildpack to use nginx as the webserver, which should allow to to configure redirects/rewrites at the webserver level, but not something I have tried. Those are just thoughts/ideas, hope it's of some help, to be honest rack middleware seems to be the simplest option if you're going to host on Heroku.